# Container type with OpenCV and OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I want to call `cv::findCountours` on some `cv::UMat` (OpenCL activated) and get the results into `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
cv::findContours(frame_umat, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::ContourApproximationModes::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Will OpenCV still able to optimise it using OpenCL even if I am using `std::vector`? Is there any advantage of using a special container like for example `cv::UMat` as a container(not an image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tracing OpenCV `cv::findContours` function, I realized that it is not optimised using OpenCL at all (not CUDA also). The only implementation it has is `SSE2` as far as I found in OpenCV 3.1